# What is temp sensor pch_wildcat_point-virtual?

Tags: lenovo, temperature, lm-sensors

Before upgrading to 16.04 I only had one "temp1" in my lm-sensors and psensor. Now I have two.

```
➜  ~ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +43.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)

thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:        2823 RPM

pch_wildcat_point-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +42.0°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +43.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +43.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +43.0°C  (high = +105.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

What is pch_wildcat_point-virtual? I tried googling, but could not really find a result. Laptop a Lenovo x1 carbon from 2015.

I did find this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Controller_Hub , but I'm not sure if this is it? And if it is, is that some point in my laptop that has a temperature sensor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Lenovo x1 carbon has an Intel H97 PCH (Platform Controller Hub), which was codenamed "Wildcat Point" during development. This "system on a chip" performs functions such as I/O (input/output) on the Gigabit LAN, SATA, PCIe & USB port and also contains various timers and controllers.

It has an internal temperature sensor located near its hottest point (the interface to the CPU) and `sensors` is reporting this. So the temperatures reported on your output (in descending order) are the CPU, the PCH, the CPU again, processor core 1 and processor core 2.

If you are interested its datasheet is here [Intel series 9 chipset datasheet](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/chipsets/9-series-chipset-pch-datasheet.html)